# Filter more times in a Java 8 Stream

Tags: list, filter, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Is it possible to filter more times in a Stream? For example if I have a list with IDs and I want to Stream a HashMap and map the key of the HashMap to key in a list and where they are match, I want to get the object from the HashMap and filter it again for example an int field in that object which is greater than 3 for example and sum them in the end. For example if its found 10 case where the list's key and HashMap's key are equal and it's filter those 10 cases and founds 3 case where for example an int field greater then 3 it gives back a sum of these in the end.

Here is my code so far:
When i try to print the list of the result of this i get this:
 java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2@70177ecd

```
somemap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> aListContainingIds.contains(e.getKey()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(n -> n.getTheOtherListFromMatchedValue().stream().filter(n -> n.getAnIntFieldFromObject() > 3))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: why don't you try it ?

Comment: I would say: yes, it is possible (*ironie off*) show us some code what you've tried

Comment: I've added the code that I've tried so far.

Comment: Just use `filter` another time instead of `map`. Also try with either `allMatch` or `anyMatch` instead of `filter` in the nested predicate.

Comment: Besides, your code doesn't compile, You're using `n -> ...` two times inside a lambda

Comment: Or, as your question is far from being clear, maybe you want to use `flatMap` instead of the second `map`, in which case the call to `filter` in the nested predicate would be correct.

Comment: I've been trying to play with filters with no success so far, I do not know what could be wrong.

Comment: Maybe reading the comments before your last one helps…

Comment: It is working now, as Federico Peralta Schaffner stated, I used flatMap instead of the second map in the Stream.

Comment: @MaxBeaver Let me write an answer with that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use [`Stream.flatMaptoInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-) (or `Stream.flatMaptoLong`) instead of just `map`:

```
int total = somemap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> aListContainingIds.contains(e.getKey()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .flatMapToInt(value -> value.getTheOtherListFromMatchedValue().stream()) 
    .filter(n -> n.getAnIntFieldFromObject() > 3)
    .sum();
```

In general, `flatMapToInt` (or `flatMap` if the stream elements are instances of some class instead of primitives) is to be used when the function you are applying returns another stream, and you want the elements of that stream to be part to the original stream.

At the end, you can get the total with the [`IntStream.sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) method.

Comment: I think, it’ll become easier to read when you move the `.filter(…)` step out of the `flatMap` function. There is no functional difference, but then, the `flatMap` function fits into one line and the subsequent `filter` doesn’t need a different indentation.

Comment: @Holger Good point, thanks. But are you absolutely sure that there's no difference, even in the case of a parallel Stream ? I mean, not only functional, but also regarding how the stream unfolds

Comment: If ever, I’d assume that moving the `filter` to the outer stream makes it more efficient. Most notably, if your predicate is a capturing lambda expression, having it within the `flatMap` function will create a new instance for every outer stream element, while having it at the outer stream will create a single predicate instance for the entire operation. Similar effects are to assume when the summing consumer is fused with the filtering operation within the stream implementation. I’m not saying that the effect will be noticeable…

Comment: @Holger Thank you